# Jcarousel scrolling erratically

Tags: javascript, jcarousel

I'm having a problem with a particular J-carousel on a page I've built.

I have managed to get other Jcarousels to work on the same page, but this particular one is having a problem scrolling:

When you click the next button it will move 1 slide forward, then 1 slide back, then 2 slides forward, 2 slides back, etc etc.

I have looked over and over at all my variable names, compared the setup. recreated it! But I just can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong!

Please could someone help me get this sorted?

The code is generated using PHP and is a bit messy.

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the reason for the erratic scrolling was because I had placed a script tag after each list item so jcarousel was trying to scroll to the non-visual script tag